# Pattern to pass computed data as prop to child component (Promise problem)

Tags: vuejs2

I am wondering how to pass a computed variable to a child-component (in a slot). The main component revieves an array of objects by using a post request. What actually happpens is that the variable "Branches" seems to be filled with an empty promise which represents the result-data. So i get a warning because the list-component expects "Branches" to be an array. I tried to delay the rendering of the slot content by using "v-if="Array.isArray(Branches)" or a flag which is set in the computed-method ("syncedBranches") but none of these seems to do it.

How to delay the rendering of that list till "Branches" is a filled array of objects? Shouldnt i use a computed var and pass the data by a getter?

Main Component

```
        <branches-widget-tabs :items="register" :activeItem="activeRegister">

                <template #tabbody_0="Branches" >

                    <h1>Content Register 1</h1>

                    <branches-widget-list :items="Branches" v-if="syncedBranches"></branches-widget-list>

                </template>

                <template #tabbody_1="Branches" v-if="Array.isArray(Branches)">

                    <h1>Content Register 2</h1>

                    <branches-widget-list :items="Branches" v-if="syncedBranches"></branches-widget-list>

                </template>

        </branches-widget-tabs>

    </div>
</template>

<style>
    #branchesWidget {
        min-width: 150px;
        min-height: 150px;
        background-color: #333;

    }
    #branchesWidget:hover {
        background-color: #666;
    }

</style>

<script>
    import chroma from 'chroma-js';
    //console.log('chroma',chroma);
    import HUSL from 'hsluv';
    //console.log('HUSL',HUSL);

    import BranchesWidgetTabs from './BranchesWidgetTabs';
    import BranchesWidgetList from './BranchesWidgetList';

    const random = function(min, max){
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    };


    var generateColors = function(n, startHex = '#ff6000', padding = 0, step = 5, randomSat = true, randomLight = true){

        let colors = [];

        const baseHex = HUSL.hexToHsluv(startHex);
        const baseHue = baseHex[0];
        //console.log('baseHue',baseHue);

        var degrees = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            degrees.push( 360 / n * i);
        }
        //console.log('degrees',degrees);

        const hues = degrees.map((offset) => {
            return (baseHue + offset) % 360;
        });
        //console.log('hues',hues);

        if(randomSat){
            var baseSaturation = random(55, 85);
        }else{
            var baseSaturation = baseHex[1];
        }

        if(randomLight){
            var baseLightness = random(35, 75);
        }else{
            var baseLightness = baseHex[2];
        }

        var subs = Math.min(n,Math.max(step,2));

        for(let i = 0; i < subs; i++) {
            colors.push( HUSL.hsluvToHex([
              hues[i],
              baseSaturation,
              baseLightness
            ]));
        }

        console.log('colors',colors);
        return chroma.scale(colors).padding(0).mode('lab').colors(n);
    };

    export default {
        name: 'BranchesWidget',
        props : [],
        data() {
            return {
                activeRegister : null,
                register : [
                    {
                        'title' : 'tab1',
                    }
                    ,
                    {
                        'title' : 'tab2',
                    }
                ],
                rawBranches : null,
                syncedBranches : false
            }
        },
        computed: {
            Branches : function(){

                if(this.rawBranches !== null){
                    let colorArr = generateColors(this.rawBranches.length);
                    console.log('colorArr',colorArr);


                    // Der Liste der Branchen die Farben zuordnen und als "Branches" bereitstellen
                    var l = [];
                    for(var i=0;i<this.rawBranches.length;i++){
                        var c = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.rawBranches[i]));
                        c.color = colorArr[i];
                        l.push(c);
                    }
                    console.log('compute Branches',l);
                    this.syncedBranches = true;
                    return l;
                }
                console.log('compute Branches',null);
                return null;
            }
        },
        components: {
            BranchesWidgetTabs,
            BranchesWidgetList
        },
        mounted () {
            axios
            .post('/assets/get',{ entity : 'industryBranches' })
                .then(response => ( this.rawBranches = response.data.data ))
        },
        created(){
            //console.log('created',this.rawData);
        },
        methods : {
            // das die Componenten eine ref mit der Bezeichnung "bwidget" hat, ist die Methode in der Seite mit app.$refs.bwidget.getBranches() erreichbar.
            getBranches : function(){
                return this.Branches;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Tabs-Compoent

```
<template>
    <div class="BranchesWidgetTabs">
        <div class="menu">
            <div class="item" v-for="(item, index) in list">
                <div>
                    <div class="i">
                        <div v-if="item.active">active</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="title">
                        {{ item.title }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="spacer"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="tabbody" v-for="(item, index) in list">
            <div class="content" v-if="item.active">
                <slot :name="`tabbody_${index}`"></slot>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<style>
    div.BranchesWidgetTabs {

        background-color: yellow;
        min-height: 40px;
    }
    div.BranchesWidgetTabs > div.menu {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
    }
    div.BranchesWidgetTabs > div.menu > .item {
        flex: 0 0 auto;
        min-width: 10px;

        background-color: blue;
        color: white;


    }

    div.BranchesWidgetTabs > div.menu > .item > div {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        padding: 0px 20px;
    }

    div.BranchesWidgetTabs > div.menu > .item:nth-child(odd) > div {
        padding-right: 0;
    }

    div.BranchesWidgetTabs > div.menu > .item > div > div {
        flex: 1;
    }
    div.BranchesWidgetTabs > div.menu > .item > div > div.i {
        background-color: darkgrey;
        min-height: 10px;
    }
    div.BranchesWidgetTabs > div.menu > .item > div > div.title {
        background-color: pink;
        padding: 10px 20px;
    }

    div.BranchesWidgetTabs > div.menu > .spacer {
        flex: 1;
    }
</style>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'BranchesWidgetTabs',
        props : {
            items : Array,
            activeItem : {
                required : true,
                validator: function(i){
                    return typeof i === 'number' || i === null;
                }
            },
        },
        data(){
            return {

            }
        },
        computed: {
            list: function(){
                var l = [];
                var s = (this.activeItem !== null)? this.activeItem : 0;
                for(var i=0;i<this.items.length;i++){
                    var c = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.items[i]));
                    if(s === i){
                        c.active = true;
                    }else{
                        c.active = false;
                    }
                    l.push(c);
                }
                return l;
            }
        },

        created(){
            console.log('created',this.activeItem);

        }
    }
</script>
```

List-Component which revieves items from main component

```
<template>
    <div class="BranchesWidgetList">
        Liste
    </div>
</template>

<style>
    div.BranchesWidgetList {

    }
</style>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'BranchesWidgetList',
        props : {
            items : Array
        },
        data(){
            return {

            }
        },
        computed: {

        },

        created(){
            console.log('created BranchesWidgetList',this.items);

        }
    }
</script>
```

[image]

EDIT:
I got it! Somehow i got misslead by the v-slot-directive. I thought i would have to pass the Branches-Array down to the child-component. But it seems that the context of template and main component is a shared one. So only thing to make sure  of is that the async-call for that array is completed by using "Branches.length" in a v-if - no need for an extra variable like "syncedBranches".

Full main component with **working** code.

```
<template>
    <div id="branchesWidget">

        <branches-widget-tabs :items="register" :activeItem="activeRegister">

                <template #tabbody_0 v-if="Branches.length">

                    <h1>Content Register 1</h1>

                    <branches-widget-list :items="Branches"></branches-widget-list>

                </template>

                <template #tabbody_1 v-if="Branches.length">

                    <h1>Content Register 2</h1>

                    <branches-widget-list :items="Branches"></branches-widget-list>

                </template>

        </branches-widget-tabs>

    </div>
</template>

<style>
    #branchesWidget {
        min-width: 150px;
        min-height: 150px;
        background-color: #333;
    }
    #branchesWidget:hover {
        background-color: #666;
    }

</style>

<script>
    import chroma from 'chroma-js';
    //console.log('chroma',chroma);
    import HUSL from 'hsluv';
    //console.log('HUSL',HUSL);

    import BranchesWidgetTabs from './BranchesWidgetTabs';
    import BranchesWidgetList from './BranchesWidgetList';

    const random = function(min, max){
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    };


    var generateColors = function(n, startHex = '#ff6000', padding = 0, step = 5, randomSat = true, randomLight = true){

        let colors = [];

        const baseHex = HUSL.hexToHsluv(startHex);
        const baseHue = baseHex[0];
        //console.log('baseHue',baseHue);

        var degrees = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            degrees.push( 360 / n * i);
        }
        //console.log('degrees',degrees);

        const hues = degrees.map((offset) => {
            return (baseHue + offset) % 360;
        });
        //console.log('hues',hues);

        if(randomSat){
            var baseSaturation = random(55, 85);
        }else{
            var baseSaturation = baseHex[1];
        }

        if(randomLight){
            var baseLightness = random(35, 75);
        }else{
            var baseLightness = baseHex[2];
        }

        var subs = Math.min(n,Math.max(step,2));

        for(let i = 0; i < subs; i++) {
            colors.push( HUSL.hsluvToHex([
              hues[i],
              baseSaturation,
              baseLightness
            ]));
        }

        console.log('colors',colors);
        return chroma.scale(colors).padding(0).mode('lab').colors(n);
    };

    export default {
        name: 'BranchesWidget',
        props : [],
        data() {
            return {
                activeRegister : null,
                register : [
                    {
                        'title' : 'tab1',
                    }
                    ,
                    {
                        'title' : 'tab2',
                    }
                ],
                rawBranches : null
            }
        },
        computed: {
            Branches : function(){
                var l = [];
                if(this.rawBranches !== null){
                    let colorArr = generateColors(this.rawBranches.length);
                    //console.log('colorArr',colorArr);

                    // Der Liste der Branchen die Farben zuordnen und als "Branches" bereitstellen
                    for(var i=0;i<this.rawBranches.length;i++){
                        var c = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.rawBranches[i]));
                        c.color = colorArr[i];
                        l.push(c);
                    }

                }
                console.log('compute Branches',l);
                return l;
            }
        },
        components: {
            BranchesWidgetTabs,
            BranchesWidgetList
        },
        mounted () {
            axios
            .post('/assets/get',{ entity : 'industryBranches' })
                .then(response => ( this.rawBranches = response.data.data ))
        },
        created(){
            //console.log('created',this.rawData);
        },
        methods : {

            getBranches : function(){
                return this.Branches;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Your computed property `Branches` should always return an Array (even empty one) but not `null`.

Comment: I tried that. The computed variable is returning an array. First time it computes, it is emtpy. Second time (after axios post) it is filled as expected. But in the rendering of the child component "this.items" logs an object. Added a screenshot in my post.To me it seems like the scoped slot attribute #tabbody_1="Branches" is not resolved and so "items" remains as unresolved promise.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the line with `return l;` and see why **l** is not an Array.

Comment: It is an array. At least in the main component. But it is not resolved in the child-component-slot. It is passed by #tabbody_1="Branches". But at the moment the slot is rendered, Branches seems to be an unresolved promise and it seems that it wont resolve when main component ajax request ist resolved

Comment: If you've found out a solution, either post an answer with your findings or delete the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it! Somehow i got misslead by the v-slot-directive. I thought i would have to pass the Branches-Array down to the child-component. But it seems that the context of template and main component is a shared one. So only thing to make sure  of is that the async-call for that array is completed by using "Branches.length" in a v-if - no need for an extra variable like "syncedBranches".

To pass the variable "Branches" as a prop there is no need for passing it in as a scoped variable. That is only needed if you want to access those data between the template tags in the main component file.

Full main component with **working** code.

```
<template>
    <div id="branchesWidget">

        <branches-widget-tabs :items="register" :activeItem="activeRegister">

                <template #tabbody_0 v-if="Branches.length">

                    <h1>Content Register 1</h1>

                    <branches-widget-list :items="Branches"></branches-widget-list>

                </template>

                <template #tabbody_1 v-if="Branches.length">

                    <h1>Content Register 2</h1>

                    <branches-widget-list :items="Branches"></branches-widget-list>

                </template>

        </branches-widget-tabs>

    </div>
</template>

<style>
    #branchesWidget {
        min-width: 150px;
        min-height: 150px;
        background-color: #333;
    }
    #branchesWidget:hover {
        background-color: #666;
    }

</style>

<script>
    import chroma from 'chroma-js';
    //console.log('chroma',chroma);
    import HUSL from 'hsluv';
    //console.log('HUSL',HUSL);

    import BranchesWidgetTabs from './BranchesWidgetTabs';
    import BranchesWidgetList from './BranchesWidgetList';

    const random = function(min, max){
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    };


    var generateColors = function(n, startHex = '#ff6000', padding = 0, step = 5, randomSat = true, randomLight = true){

        let colors = [];

        const baseHex = HUSL.hexToHsluv(startHex);
        const baseHue = baseHex[0];
        //console.log('baseHue',baseHue);

        var degrees = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            degrees.push( 360 / n * i);
        }
        //console.log('degrees',degrees);

        const hues = degrees.map((offset) => {
            return (baseHue + offset) % 360;
        });
        //console.log('hues',hues);

        if(randomSat){
            var baseSaturation = random(55, 85);
        }else{
            var baseSaturation = baseHex[1];
        }

        if(randomLight){
            var baseLightness = random(35, 75);
        }else{
            var baseLightness = baseHex[2];
        }

        var subs = Math.min(n,Math.max(step,2));

        for(let i = 0; i < subs; i++) {
            colors.push( HUSL.hsluvToHex([
              hues[i],
              baseSaturation,
              baseLightness
            ]));
        }

        console.log('colors',colors);
        return chroma.scale(colors).padding(0).mode('lab').colors(n);
    };

    export default {
        name: 'BranchesWidget',
        props : [],
        data() {
            return {
                activeRegister : null,
                register : [
                    {
                        'title' : 'tab1',
                    }
                    ,
                    {
                        'title' : 'tab2',
                    }
                ],
                rawBranches : null
            }
        },
        computed: {
            Branches : function(){
                var l = [];
                if(this.rawBranches !== null){
                    let colorArr = generateColors(this.rawBranches.length);
                    //console.log('colorArr',colorArr);

                    // Der Liste der Branchen die Farben zuordnen und als "Branches" bereitstellen
                    for(var i=0;i<this.rawBranches.length;i++){
                        var c = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.rawBranches[i]));
                        c.color = colorArr[i];
                        l.push(c);
                    }

                }
                console.log('compute Branches',l);
                return l;
            }
        },
        components: {
            BranchesWidgetTabs,
            BranchesWidgetList
        },
        mounted () {
            axios
            .post('/assets/get',{ entity : 'industryBranches' })
                .then(response => ( this.rawBranches = response.data.data ))
        },
        created(){
            //console.log('created',this.rawData);
        },
        methods : {

            getBranches : function(){
                return this.Branches;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```